# is there a way to get rid of loaded clojure classes?

Tags: clojure

When run, the following creates a bunch of classes that gets loaded

```
(dotimes [i 1000000]
  (eval `(fn [] (+ ~i 10))))
```

It's possible to inspect the objects by connecting to visualvm:

[image: If too many objects are created, the vm crashes.]

At some point, the vm decides to unload the objects but it's rather arbitrary. Is there a way of unloading these objects when there are 100k loaded instead of at 500k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider why you want to get rid of them. Just lying around they're not doing anything except consuming memory, so I imagine you would like to reduce your memory footprint. So, tell the JVM that. I'm not an expert on JVM flags or performance, but my understanding is that in modern JVMs, loaded classes are GCed in a way similar to ordinary objects, but stored in a separate area called MetaSpace. If you know that your program never needs very many classes loaded at once you can limit that space by setting JVM option `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`.

Comment: thanks. that helps quite a lot. I see the metaspace tab on the visualvm. I'll play around with the settings to see what happens with gc.

Comment: I have a test suite and it's been crashing. I'm still trying to figure out whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

As per @amalloy's suggestion. Setting `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m` produces this (which is the required effect)

[image]